# I get this error while using HTML Agility Pack: system.net.http.httprequestexception' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, web, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have a web scraping application, in which I retrieve information from a website.
It was working fine till yesterday and now I am getting errors.

Before the error was as mentioned above.
Now, it includes:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

However, I get these errors.

Can anybody please help?

```
try
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

                var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

                var webListHtml = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("style", "")
                    .Equals("font-weight: bold; font-size:16px; text-align:left; padding-left:5px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px"));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I caught the error" + e.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may see if this works:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

But keep in mind that it's not a great idea from a security standpoint. You'll have to decide if it's okay for your purposes here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. I am working on a personal machine and personal project, so security is no issue. I mean, what I don't understand is that it was working absolutely fine just hours ago. I haven't changed anything and it is giving me these errors.

Comment: @mrkn0007 Hmm... something has changed somewhere... I recently had a .Net Framework Cumulative Update break some simple code... As a next step I would recommend checking the server's certificate in a web browser. You may also check into `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`. I'm guessing you don't own the server, or you wouldn't be scrapping it... A lot of companies are switching everything to TLS and dropping SSL. I *think* Stack Overflow recently did this, for example. Because your issues started on the 1st day (**work** day) of the month, this seems plausible. I hope this helps!